# how to map a component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a todo-list which I've done with an array. I want to replace the array with a component and I want ask how to list component old version with array:

```
let param=this.state.list.map(function(x , index) {
  if (!self.state.editing) {
    return(
      <li key={"etudiant_"+index}>{x} 
        <button onClick={(index) => {self.delete(index)}}>delete</button> 
        <button onClick={() => {self.edit()}}>Edit</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. "I want to replace the array with a component and I want ask how to list component old version with array" What do you mean?? You need to provide more code examples for what you're trying to achieve. I can't tell if this is old code or new code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Digringo! Please try and keep the formatting of your questions a bit cleaner next time you make a post. Keep your code properly indented so that it is easy to read. Also, please try to write in proper english; capitalize letters (e.g "I'm" instead of "i'm"), write whole words (e.g "with" instead of "wit") and refrain using slag (e.g "gonna"). --- The more effort you put into writing a good post, the higher the chances someone will help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is but the way to do it with components should be very similar to the one you posted but using the todoItem component (or whatever the item it is).

```
render() {
   const { list } = this.state;

   return (
      <TodoList>
         {
            list.map((item, idx) =>
               <ListItem key={'student_'+idx} onClick={() => 
                  (...)}>itemName</ListItem> 
            )
         }
      </TodoList>
   );
}
```

Comment: think i have to explain more so:
i have the todo list stocked in array in the state, and to render it i'm maping it the code is working great but i don't wanna use an array anymore so i want to make every todo item in component and then map these component, it's simple to map an array so i wanna know how to do it with component, i hope it's clear

Comment: @Digringo You still need an array. You'll just create an array of components.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want every item as another React component. So my suggestion is to keep them as dumb as possible so you handle possible changes from outside.

```
const Item = ({ children, index, onDelete, onEdit }) => 
  <li>
    {children}
    <button onClick={() => onDelete(index)}>Delete</button> 
    <button onClick={() => onEdit(index)}>Edit</button>
  </li>
```

And then from outside:

```
handleDelete(index) {
  ...
}

handleEdit(index) {
  ...
}

render() {
  const { editing, list } = this.state

  return (
    <div>
      {!editing && list.map((item, index) =>
        <Item
          key={index}
          index={index}
          onDelete={this.handleDelete}
          onEdit={this.handleEdit}
       >
         {item}
       </Item>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```